# Label fires click function twice

Tags: jquery, click, label

Is any way to call a function and at the same time save effect on the radiobutton by clicking label?

Example (I need open/close fieldsets with checkboxes by clicking labels for radiobuttons)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>Click on Label</title>

<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 

accordionOptions();

});
function accordionOptions(){

$("label.legend, label.childless").click( function(event){

var opposites = $(".subtype").not($(this).next());

var el = $(this);

opposites.find("input:checked").attr('checked', false);

opposites.removeClass("expanded");

el.siblings("label").removeClass("expanded");

el.next(".subtype").toggleClass("expanded");

el.toggleClass("expanded");

}); 

}

</script>

<style type="text/css">

<!--

HTML { text-align: center}

BODY { background: #FFF; color: #494949; font: .813em/140% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; margin: 4em auto; width: 240px}

LABEL { display: block; margin-bottom: .6em}

.subtype { display: none}

.expanded { display: block !important}

.label.expanded { /*styling selected fieldset heading*/}

-->

</style>

</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">

<fieldset>

<label class="legend expanded"><input name="rb_item" type="radio" value="" checked="checked" />Item 0100</label>

<fieldset class="subtype expanded">

<label><input name="item01" type="checkbox" value="" />Item 0101</label>

<label><input name="item01" type="checkbox" value="" />Item 0102</label>

</fieldset>

<label class="childless"><input name="rb_item" type="radio" value="" />Item 0200</label>

<label class="legend"><input name="rb_item" type="radio" value="" />Item 0300</label>

<fieldset class="subtype">

<label><input name="item03" type="checkbox" value="" />Item 0301</label>

<label><input name="item03" type="checkbox" value="" />Item 0302</label>

</fieldset>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</fieldset>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `$().change()`. When you click on a lable of a `radiobutton || checkbox` the `change-event` is fired. So dont try to fix your `click event`, just use the `change event`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `e.preventDefault();` is it stops the label click from checking the radio button.

A better solution would be to simply add a "is checked" quick check like so:

```
$("label").click(function(e){
  var rbtn = $(this).find("input");
  if(rbtn.is(':checked')){
    **All the code you want to have happen on click**
  }
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the focus event on the radio button instead.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
        accordionOptions();
    });
    var accordionOptions = function(){
        $("label.legend > input, label.childless > input").focus(function(event) {
            var el = $(this).parent();
            var opposites = $(".subtype").not(el.next());
            opposites.find("input:checked").attr("checked", false);
            opposites.removeClass("expanded");
            el.siblings("label").removeClass("expanded");
            el.next(".subtype").toggleClass("expanded");
            el.toggleClass("expanded");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I repeat reoly for previous solution. It's cool. But in this case attribute toggleClass of label and next fieldset.subtype has no effect. It will obvious if we'll add new design rule to .expanded class (for example .expanded { display: block !important; background: #FCC}.

Answer (score 0):

```
- $("label.legend, label.childless").click( function(event){
+ $("label, input").click( function(event){
```

... and then some cosmetics to keep radio labels at place.

Comment: Thanks, Andrejs. It's cool solution. But in this case attribute toggleClass of label and next fieldset.subtype has no effect. It will obvious if we'll add new design rule to .expanded class (for example .expanded { display: block !important; background: #FCC}.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my end:

```
$("label.legend, label.childless").click( function(event){
  var opposites = $(".subtype").not($(this).next());
  var el = $(this);
  opposites.find("input:checked").removeAttr('checked');
  opposites.removeClass("expanded");
  el.siblings("label").removeClass("expanded");
  el.next(".subtype").addClass("expanded");
  el.toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

That being exchanging toggleClass for addClass.